# How to optimise multi dimension numpy array calculation?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, coding-efficiency

Given a 5D array, the objective is to calculate the difference between the extracted two arrays. For simplicity, say to measure the difference at the second position which can be denoted as `bt` and `lf`. The value from these two array can be extracted as follows:

```
arr[ep, bt, mt, bd, :] - arr[ep, lf, mt, bd, :]
```

Note that in the above, the index for the first (`ep`), third (`mt`) and fourth (`bd`) axes are the same for both of the arrays, with only the position index of second axis differing (`bt` and `lf`).

Based on this requirement, the following code was proposed, and pack under the function `nested_for_loop`:

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
np.random.seed(0)

ub_lb_pair = np.tril_indices (5, -1)

arr = np.random.randn(3, 5, 4, 3, 2)
my_shape = arr.shape

def nested_for_loop():
    store_cval = np.full([my_shape[0], 10, my_shape[2], my_shape[3], my_shape[4]],
                         np.nan)  # preallocate
    for ep in range(0, my_shape[0]):
        for mt in range(0, my_shape[2]):
            for bd in range(0, my_shape[3]):
                for idx,(bt, lf) in enumerate(zip(ub_lb_pair[0], ub_lb_pair[1])):
                    store_cval[ep, idx, mt, bd, :] = arr[ep, bt, mt, bd, :] - \
                                                     arr[ep, lf, mt, bd, :]
    return store_cval


store_cval = nested_for_loop()
```

However, I would like to make the code much more compact and efficient if possible.

One approach I can think of is take advantage of the `joblib parallel` module, which can be achieve as below as shown under the function `multi_prop`.

```
def multi_prop(my_arr, ep):
    temp_ = np.full([10, my_shape[2], my_shape[3], my_shape[4]],
                    np.nan)
    for mt in range(0, my_shape[2]):
        for bd in range(0, my_shape[3]):
            for idx, (bt, lf) in enumerate(zip(ub_lb_pair[0], ub_lb_pair[1])):
                temp_[idx, mt, bd, :] = my_arr[ep, bt, mt, bd, :] - my_arr[ep, lf, mt, bd, :]
                x = 1
    return  temp_

dist_abs = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(multi_prop)(arr, ep) for ep in range(0, my_shape[0]))

dist_abs = np.array(dist_abs)
bb = np.array_equal(store_cval, dist_abs)
```

But, I wonder whether the is a more numpythonic way to achieve the same objective.

Comment: Why a slice for just the last dimension?  `arr[:,bt,:,:,:] and arr[:,lf,:,:,:]` or even `arr[:,bt,...] and arr[:,lf,...]`?

Comment: Say the last last dimension is of shape 2 and, and each of having the value `[3,4]` and `[1,1]` . So the diffrence between them are `[2,3]`. Does this make sense to you @hpaulj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need any loops at all. Imagine this pair of fancy indices:

```
bt, lf = np.tril_indices (5, -1)
```

You are looking for

```
store_cval = arr[:, bt] - arr[:, lf]
```

Keep in mind that `store_cval[ep, idx, mt, bd, :] = arr[ep, bt, mt, bd, :] - arr[ep, lf, mt, bd, :]` is an implicit loop over the last index. They're all loops, and you don't need any of them over the hood.

A more general solution:

```
def diffs(arr, axis):
    a, b = np.tril_indices(arr.shape[axis], -1)
    ind1 = [slice(None) for _ in range(arr.ndim)]
    ind2 = ind1.copy()
    ind1[axis] = a
    ind2[axis] = b
    return arr[tuple(ind1)] - arr[tuple(ind2)]
```

Comment: Hi @Mad, thanks for the detail explaination. For some reason, I am unable to reproduce the above result. For example, what is the value of `axis`. Also, my compiler provide the warning `End of statement expected` on the line `ind1 = [slice(None) for _ in range arr.ndim]`. And finally, do you mean `tril` to be `np.tril_indices `?

Comment: @balandongiv. Sorry about the typos. Fixed now. In your case, you want to use combinations along the second axis, so `axis=1`